# Connecting to Azure Redis Enterprise from CLI

Tags: azure, redis

I am trying to connect to Redis Enterprise on Azure cloud and followed the steps here.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-redis-cli-tool.md

But I get an error like

```
C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli.exe -p 10000 -a <access key/password>

127.0.0.1:10000> ping

Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

What else should I check?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Redis cluster really listening on port 10000, and not 6380 (TLS) or 6379 (non-TLS)?

Comment: This is the port in the endpoint. I did try with 6380 and 6379 as well. Seems like some other network connectivity set up that's missing.

Comment: Able to connect using instructions here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/connect-to-azure-cache-for-redis-using-ssl-port-6380-from-linux/ba-p/1186109 from an AKS cluster in the cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided, you are connecting to "localhost" (127.0.0.1)

To connect to your Azure Cache for Redis instance, you need to provide the hostname as well:

```
redis-cli -h <hostname> -p 10000 -a <access key/password>
```

Comment: No, what worked is following this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/connect-to-azure-cache-for-redis-using-ssl-port-6380-from-linux/ba-p/1186109  from an AKS cluster on the Azure environment, also because the endpoint is not available outside